# Android: Can't toggle visibility after migrating from kotlin synthetic to databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, deprecated

As `kotlin synthetic` got deprecated (like every stuff gets in android for no reason), I am currently working to fully migrate to `databinding`. A problem I am now encountering is, that I for example can't toggle the visibility of an imported layout, it simply says

> Unresolved reference: visibility

And this makes even sense, because the variable I am getting from my layout `(calibrateRepairBtnView)` is another type of `binding` which has no function `visibility`.

My question is: How can I solve this WITHOUT writing 10 lines of code, where I toggle the visibility of every item inside my calibrateRepairBtnView? Am I missing something here?

### Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CalibrateRepairMessageFragment : BaseCalibrateRepairFragment<FragmentCalibrateRepairMessageBinding>(
    R.layout.fragment_calibrate_repair_message,
) {
    private val calibrateRepairMessageBinding: FragmentCalibrateRepairMessageBinding by viewBinding()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun sucessState() {
        calibrateRepairMessageBinding.calibrateRepairBtnView.visibility // not working anymore
        calibrate_repair_btn_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE // worked before
    }
```

### Layout (imported)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="price"
            type="Float" />
        <variable
            name="btnText"
            type="String" />
        <variable
            name="btnIcon"
            type="android.graphics.drawable.Drawable" />
        <variable
            name="btnTextCapitalized"
            type="Boolean" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="124dp"
            android:background="@color/color_btn_gray"
            android:clickable="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_sum"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:text="@string/calibrate_btn_price"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_price"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{price}"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:text="4800.00"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_sum"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/calibbrate_btn_tv_intern_curr"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_sum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calibbrate_btn_tv_intern_curr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/currency"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textHeadlineNormal2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_price" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/calibrate_btn_desc"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_next"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_tv_price" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_btn_next"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/big16dpMargin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/standard8dpMargin"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:text="@{btnText}"
            android:textAllCaps="@{btnTextCapitalized}"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textDescriptionNormal1"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/color_btn_blue"
            app:icon="@{btnIcon}"
            app:iconGravity="textStart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/calibrate_btn_background" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### Layout (fragment)

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="com.kofigyan.stateprogressbar.StateProgressBar.StateNumber" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.app.framework.ui.viewmodel.EmailViewModel" />
        <variable
            name="outsideTT"
            type="String" />
    </data>

       <!-- USING THE LAYOUT HERE (binding.calibrateRepairBtnView.visibility) -->
        <include
            android:id="@+id/calibrate_repair_btn_view"
            layout="@layout/app_standard_checkout_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:price="@{viewModel.price}"
            app:btnText="@{@string/calibrate_btn_text}"
            app:btnTextCapitalized="@{true}" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to solve this problem. Instead of doing `calibrateRepairMessageBinding.calibrateRepairBtnView.visibility` I did `calibrateRepairMessageBinding.calibrateRepairBtnView.root.visibility`. As roots says

> Returns the outermost View in the layout file associated with the Binding. If this
> binding is for a merge layout file, this will return the first root in the merge tag.

With this, the `root object` (should) return the outermost view, which is the `constraintlayout` associated with the view. Toggling the `constrainslayouts` view would toggle the entire view, therefore this suited my case.

If someone has a better answer or thinks that this might be wrong, feel free to leave a comment or provide a better answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

`android:visibility="@{viewModel.boolean? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE, default=gone}"`

here I've just added boolean so that you can define your own condition

Comment: No, this is not a good answer, because the example I provided in my question is just simplified. If I do this, I will mixup my viewModel with some UI-Logic which is hideous and I will never understand this 6 months later

Comment: As far as i know using databinding within ViewModel is a best practice so I follow this way

Comment: But that is not what I mean. My question is: Why can't I access the `visibility` variable..